# Initializing Primitive Array to One Value

Tags: c++, integer, primitive-types, zero

Is there a way to initialize an array of primitives, say a integer array, to 0? Without using a for loop? Looking for concise code that doesn't involve a for loop.

:)

Comment: Exactly why are you trying to avoid a for loop?  There's different possible answers here, and they do affect the advice you might get.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of something.

Answer (score 19):

```
int array[10] = {}; // to 0

std::fill(array, array + 10, x); // to x
```

---

Note if you want a more generic way to get the end:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T* endof(T (&pArray)[N])
{
    return &pArray[0] + N;
}
```

To get:

```
std::fill(array, endof(array), x); // to x (no explicit size)
```

---

It should be mentioned `std::fill` is just a wrapper around the loop you're trying to avoid, and `= {};` might be implemented in such terms.

Comment: Deleted my answer (yours just says the same thing but much clearer -- and I like the template solution!). I'd give you +1 but I'm out of votes... again.

Comment: @Billy: Heh, thanks. You and your votes. :) (Or lack thereof.)

Comment: @Billy: I've upvoted it, I'll grant you half of my vote if you wish :p

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible. The initialization method depends on the context.

If you are declaring a static or local array, use `= {}` initializer

```
int a[100] = {};  // all zeros
```

If you are creating an array with `new[]`, use `()` initializer

```
int *a = new int[100](); // all zeros
```

If you are initializing a non-static member array in the constructor initializer list, use `()` initializer

```
class C {
  int a[100];

  C() : a() // all zeros
  {
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is the zero-initialization documented?  I thought one of the things in C/C++ you could NOT count on was that it would be initialized to anything at all?  In fact, that's a BENEFIT of C/C++ over Java (sometimes), since that language guarantees that for certain types, whereas C/C++ doesn't take the (slight) performance hit, and gives you the memory "as-is".

Comment: @Kevin: What do you mean? If you leave out any of the initializers above, the arrays remain uninitialized.

Comment: @Kevin: It does give you the memory "as is", unless you *explicitly ask* for zeroes. When you explicitly use initializers like `= {}` or `()`, you expliciutly ask for value-initialization, which boils down to zero-initialization for basic types. For example, if you do `new int[100]`, you get memory "as is", but if you do `new int[100]()` you get zeros. It is that `()` that makes all the difference.

Comment: @Kevin: It is all documented in the strandard. It is spread across several different places though: aggregates *and their initializers), `new`, and initializing bases and members.

Answer (score 1):

You can use memset if you want all your values to be zero.  Also, if you're only looking to initialize to zero, you can declare your array in such a way that it is placed in the ZI section of memory.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is zero you could also use memset (though this is more C-style):

```
int a[100];
memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

`double A[10] = { value }; // initialize A to value`.
I do not remember if value has to be compiled constant or not.
will not work with automatic arrays

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of concealing what you are doing with different syntax, and this is what the other answers give you - `std::fill, memset, ={}` etc. In the general case, though (excluding compiler-specific tricks like the ZI one), think about what needs to be done by the compiled code:

- it needs to know where your memory
  block/array starts;
- it needs to set each element of the
  block to the value in turn;
- it needs to check repeatedly whether
  the end of the block has been reached.

In other words, there *needs* to be a loop in a fairly fundamental way.