# Trouble initialising array in G++

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

I have tried initialising my `int cate[catNum]` array into all `1`s, when `cout<<cate[1]`, it outputs `0`? I don't know what the problem is, theoretically it should be 1?

```
int main ()
{
    int const catNum = 13;    
    int cate[catNum]= {1};
    cout<<cate[1]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not `1`, theoretically or otherwise. You've initialized the first element to `1` and the remaining to `0`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625551/initializing-primitive-array-to-one-value for multiple ways to initialize all the elements in the array to the same value.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1352370/241631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int cate[catNum]= {1};
```

This syntax initializes the first element to 1 and the rest to 0. (Technically, it *value-initializes* the rest.)

Try,

```
std::fill( std::begin( cate ), std::end( cate ), 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `cate` as an array of 13 integers, but the initializer `{1}` has only one integer, so you only initialized the first element to 1.  To set them all, you could do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < catNum; i++) { cate[i] = 1; }
```